# Change elements of beamer table step-by-step

Tags: tables, beamer

I have seen questions about how to add elements to a table in beamer step-by-step, but I am interested in changing existing elements of a table step-by-step. Here is a simple example:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\toprule
H1 & H2 & H3\\
\midrule
1 & ? & 3 \\
2 & 4 & ?\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

For example, I would like the ? in the first row after the header to first appear as is, but then when I press the arrow to go to the next slide, it is in a \framebox{}, or has color, something like that.

Is there a way to do this with \onslide{}?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\toprule
H1 & H2 & H3\\
\midrule
1 & \only<2>{\cellcolor{blue!50}}? & 3 \\
2 & 4 & ?\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also just found this link to be helpful: https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/20/beamer-series-pt4.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\only`. For example:

```latex
1 & \only<1>{?}\only<2>{somethingelse} & 3
```

The parameter in `<>` specify when it will be displayed. You can also use ranges:

- `\only<1-3>{abc}`: Display `abc` for the first 3 steps
- `\only<2->{abc}`: Display nothing on the first step, then display `abc` for each following step